# How to make the sidebar full width to completely fill one side only?

Tags: html, css, sidebar, column-width

I have a container with `max-width: 800px;`, inside it there are two columns, col_1 and col_2, everything works as expected. For the initial code, if you put the page in full screen, col_1 is a long red column. To the left of the red column there is nothing, only white color. I want that white space to the left of col_1 to become the same color as col_1.

**Update**: Currently doing this with gradient background as recommended by user tobiv. But that's not always a good solution. For example, when loading pages, as the body tag is loaded first, the annoying gradient is displayed.

How can I achieve this goal?

**Here is an example**: https://www.uxlibrary.org/explore/ui-design/articles/design-systems

**Here is the structure of my code**:

```css
body {
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, red 0%, red 50%, white 50%);
}

.container_one {
  display: block;
  max-width: 800px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  background: white;
}

.container_two {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

.col_1, .col_2 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

/*Col Width */
.col_1 { 
  width: 20%; 
  border-right: 1px solid gray;
  padding-right: 15px;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  align-self: flex-start;
  height: 100vh;
  background: red;
}

.col_2 { 
  width: 80%; 
  padding-left: 15px;
}

.element {
  background: #f3f3f3;
  margin: 5px 0; 
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container_one">
  <div class="container_two">
   <div class="col_1">
      <span class="element">Element 1</span>
      <span class="element">Element 2</span>
      <span class="element">Element 3</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col_2">
      <span class="element">Element 1</span>
      <span class="element">Element 2</span>
      <span class="element">Element 3</span>
      <span class="element">Element 4</span>
      <span class="element">Element 5</span>
      <span class="element">Element 1</span>
      <span class="element">Element 2</span>
      <span class="element">Element 3</span>
      <span class="element">Element 4</span>
      <span class="element">Element 5</span>
      <span class="element">Element 1</span>
      <span class="element">Element 2</span>
      <span class="element">Element 3</span>
      <span class="element">Element 4</span>
      <span class="element">Element 5</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I do not understand what you want to achieve (nor what you have initially since the code you gave does not match the screenshot) :o

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understood your question, but here is an example:

#### HTML

```
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="left-side--container">
      <div class="col_1">
        <span class="element">Element 1</span>
        <span class="element">Element 2</span>
        <span class="element">Element 3</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col_2">
      <span class="element">Element 1</span>
      <span class="element">Element 2</span>
      <span class="element">Element 3</span>
      <span class="element">Element 4</span>
      <span class="element">Element 5</span>
      <span class="element">Element 1</span>
      <span class="element">Element 2</span>
      <span class="element">Element 3</span>
      <span class="element">Element 4</span>
      <span class="element">Element 5</span>
      <span class="element">Element 1</span>
      <span class="element">Element 2</span>
      <span class="element">Element 3</span>
      <span class="element">Element 4</span>
      <span class="element">Element 5</span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <body>
```

#### CSS

```css
* { margin: 0; padding: 0;}

.container {
  display: flex;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.col_1, .col_2 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.left-side--container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  width: 30%;
  background: #FC664E;
}

.col_1 {
  width: 40%;
  border-right: 1px solid gray;
  padding-right: 15px;
  height: 100vh;
  background: red;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

.col_2 { 
  width: 800px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  background: gray;
}

.element {
  padding: 10px;
  font-family: arial;
}
```

You only have to change `#FC664E` color to red.

Comment: Thanks was what I was trying to do, your code is correct even if I will customize it according to my needs. Thanks so much for your time.

Answer (score 1):

If you add a white (or other solid color) background to your main container, you can just add a gradient background with a hard center (so it's not really a gradient, rather a stripe) to the body:

```
.container_one {
    /* ... */
    background: white;
}

body {
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, red 0%, red 50%, white 50%);
}
```

Comment: Excuse my bad explanation. But that's not what I'm looking for. I want the white space to the left of col_1 to become the same color as col_1. As it happens here for example:https://www.uxlibrary.org/explore/ui-design/articles/design-systems

Comment: In the way you suggest, if the screen size changes the gradient also covers the main container, so it would have to be adapted with media query and it becomes too long a job.

Comment: @Snorlax That works exactly like that though. Just add a solid background to main container, so it covers part of the background gradient so it's only visible to the left side.

Comment: Thank you for your time and response. It works but I don't know how effective it can be as a solution. I need to figure out if it fits the project and if I really want to set a white color for all of my main containers.

Comment: Ok, I tried and the result is as it should be, only in my case when the pages are loaded you can see the body and its gradient first. So I want to find a way to do the same thing but apply it directly to the sidebar, like on this site: https://www.uxlibrary.org/explore/ui-design/articles/design-systems